# Why are WMS layers not loading on new computer?

Tags: qgis

I've created a QGIS project that makes use of WMS layers.  I'm sharing the project with many other computers. However when I load the QGIS project on those computers, the wms layers do not load.  even once I've added the wms server to the WMS layer manager it still doesn't load.  the only way that seems to work is to actaully load the WMS layers again into the project....obviously a pain since I have several layers from various sources.

Any ideas?  Is there a proper methodology for doing this?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Create a new simple project, load a WMS, save it, and compare the .qgs-files with the old ones with a good text editor, e.g. notepad++. If you found the difference in < datasource >, you can edit the qgs-files with notepad++. It can open several files at once, and do search&replace on all opened files.